# node.js do not work after deploy on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am new to node.js and Heroku, I just have deployed for the first time a node.js app to Heroku and when I ran in Heroku, the application did not run so I used the command `heroku logs --tail` but I had this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JghRB.png)

For idea, my node.js works very fine without Heroku but stop working after deploying it there

Here my index.js:

```js
const express = require("express");
var md5 = require('md5');
var reverseMd5 = require('reverse-md5');
const app = express();
const userRouter = require("./API/users/user.router");
const operationsRouter = require("./API/operations/operations.router");


app.use(express.json());

app.use("", userRouter);
app.use("", operationsRouter);
app.use(express.static('images'));

const port = process.env.APP_PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("server up and running on PORT :", port);
});
```

Hero my config file java:

```js
const { createPool } = require("mysql");
const pool = createPool({
    host: 'host.example.com',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'database',
    connectionLimit: 100,
    multipleStatements: true
});
module.exports = pool;
```

What shocked me is that why these errors show up only after deploying on Heroku?
Is there anything I can do to fix this problem?

Comment: Make sure to remove the credentials in your question, and reset them with your database provider.

Comment: it is not paid database , it is a free database host just for testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku dynamically assigns your app a port, so you can't set the port to a fixed number. Heroku adds the port to the env, so you can pull it from there. Switch your `APP_PORT` listen to this:

```js
.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000)
```

Make sure you have changed the `APP_PORT` to `PORT`.
That way it'll still listen to port 5000 when you test locally, but it will also work on Heroku.

One more thing I can see that you are using Nodemon on Heroku which is not necessary on Heroku. So remove the Nodemon from your Heroku and declare a `Procfile`

```
web: node app.js
```

Being `app.js` the entry point to your app.